# "algumas pessoas choram, e outras vendem lenços" - In which context can we use this saying?

Tags: significado, ditados

IN ENGLISH - I had never heard it before but heard it twice during the past few months. I wasn't paying attention but the somewhat sarcastic tone caught me. As it was mentioned at the end of an interview, I can't say anything about context. I thought of a few situations where someone might say it but wondered whether it was specific for only one. Therefore, my question is: **in what context does this saying fit?**  **Have you ever heard it?**

IN PORTUGUESE Eu nunca tinha ouvido antes mas, por duas vezes nos últimos meses, eu ouvi esse ditado.  Confesso que não prestei atenção ao contexto e, em uma das vezes, a frase foi dita no final de uma entrevista com uma intonação possivelmente sarcástica

> - "É, algumas pessoas choram. E outras pessoas vendem lenços".

Pensei em algumas situações onde seria possível usá-lo, mas acredito que exista um contexto específico para tal.   **Em que situação costumamos usar esse ditado? Tu já ouviste alguma vez?**

Comment: Eu não conhecia *intonação*.

Comment: I am familiar with that expression, I live in São Paulo - Brazil. Jacinto's answer is appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Foi a primeira vez que encontrei esta expressão. A primeira coisa que me ocorreu, tal como ao Artefacto, foi que uns sofrem, e outros conseguem beneficiar com isso. Possivelmente de forma perfeitamente lícita: afinal não há nada de errado em vender lenços. Veio-me à ideia uma agência funerária.

Depois de uma vista de olhos pela net, cheguei a outra conclusão. O melhor uso da expressão é para descrever duas atitudes opostas perante uma adversidade: uns lamentam-se e baixam os braços; outros arregaçam as mangas e tentam encontrar no meio da adversidade oportunidades para singrar e dar a volta por cima, possivelmente beneficiando da passividade dos primeiros. Nesta interpretação, os que choram são essencialmente vítimas da sua própria passividade. O melhor exemplo que encontrei foi este artigo sobre a crise num setor industrial numa cidade no interior de São Paulo, [os que choram e os que vendem lenços:](http://www.anthropos.com.br/280-textos-de-motivacao-e-sucesso/240-os-que-choram-e-os-que-vendem-lenos.html)

> "Crise para os outros. A verdade é que nós estamos sabendo da globalização e do aumento da competitividade há quanto tempo? Por isso viemos nos preparando. Já há alguns anos fazemos programas de qualidade e produtividade e nos preparamos para este momento. E os outros? A verdade é que enquanto nós trabalhávamos 12 horas por dia em direção à modernidade, os outros empresários da cidade formavam comissões para falar com deputados, secretários e ministros pedindo proteção ao setor.... Hoje estão todos quebrados. Não entenderam o tempo em que estamos vivendo."

Em quase todos os outros casos, a expressão é usada de forma mais vaga. Em geral aponta o erro da passividade e acomodação e aconselha uma atitude ativa e combativa para singrar na vida. Agora, não há aqui qualquer razão para sarcasmo. O tom sarcástico detetado pelo Centaurus na entrevista leva-me a crer que a expressão tenha sido empregue aí com outro sentido, possivelmente no tal sentido de uns se aproveitarem das desgraças dos outros. Não me parece que a expressão assente aí tão bem como para exprimira a oposição passividade/combatividade, mas cada um é livre de a utilizar como quiser.

Comment: O fato de que os portugueses conservam o "t" antes de "c" é de meu conhecimento há muito tempo.  Interessante é saber que vocês o omitem justamente em uma das poucas palavras em que ele é mantido em ptBR: "detectado".

Comment: @Centarus Não desde que o AO90 entrou em vigor. De qualquer forma, no Brasil parece haver maior tendência para pronunciar (e portanto escrever) essas consoantes: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-novo-acordo-ortografico-e-a-variacao-regional/31614 : cacto, caracteres, concepção, recepção, peremptório -- em todas estas não se pronuncia (e portanto não se escreve desde que o acordo entrou em vigor) o c ou o p.

Comment: @Centaurus, O que aconteceu foi que o Brasil suprimiu em 1943 todos os **c** e **p** mudos, enquanto Portugal manteve os **c** e **p** mudos que eram precedidos de vogal aberta, como em *detectar* que em Portugal é pronunciado /dətɛˈtar/ (ɛ é som **é**). Era por isso que nós tínhamos tantas palavras com *ct, cç, pt, pç*. Na maioria delas o **c** e o **p** eram mudos, e com o AO90 deixaram de se excrever, de modo que agora temos menos dessas palavras que vocês no Brasil.

Comment: Não, o acordo é só ortográfico. Eu vou escrever "detetar" mas provavelmente vou continuar dizendo "detectar".  Afinal, passei a vida inteira pronunciando esses "c's" e "p's" e agora querem que eu mude? (risos)

Comment: Não é nada disso. *Detectar/detetar* é uma das palavras com dupla grafia prevista no AO90. A ideia é cada um escrever como pronuncia: os brasileiros escreverão *detectar*, os portugueses, *detetar*. O meu comentário anterior era só para explicar a razão de antes do AO90 se escrever também *detectar* em Portugal apesar de o **c** não ser aqui pronunciado.

Answer (score 2):

Nunca ouvi, mas diria que significa que existem pessoas que tiram proveito (por exemplo, financeiro) das desgraças dos outros. É de resto este o significado descrito [nesta página](http://pensador.uol.com.br/frase/ODU2NDI0/):

> Enquanto uns choram, outros vendem lenços. É a filosofia da vida, enquanto você estiver mal, sempre terá alguem se beneficiando com isso.

Noutros resultados que encontrei, todavia, não parece que o lucro daqueles que "vendem lenços" seja graças aos "que choram". O significado parece ser simplesmente "uns estão bem, outros estão mal". Parecem ir mais nesta linha os resultados relacionados com [um livro intitulado "Enquanto uns Choram... Outros vendem lenços"](http://qualitymark.com.br/enquanto-uns-choram-outros-vendem-lencos) e outros relacionados com a crise económica (incluindo [este artigo](http://www.mtmaldonado.com.br/entrevistas/chorar_vender_lencos.php)).